# Como fazer imagem ficar acima do texto com media queries

Tags: html5, css3, media-queries

Tenho um slide que possui uns `keyframes` para fazer uma animação basíca porem preciso adicionar uma `media queries` que quando a minha tela tiver no máximo `800px` queria que a minha imagem que está do lado esquerdo fica-se acima do texto logo o texto iria ficar abaixo da imagem ambos centralizados na minha section porem eu tentei e ele nem se move eu não sei se isso pode ser feito com `float` ou outra coisa segue meu código:

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans");

/* Positioning */

#slider #slides_image .slide.one {
  left: 400px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOne 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeOne 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeOne 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_image .slide.two {
  left: 900px;
  top: 500px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-animation: fadeTwo 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeTwo 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeTwo 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_image .slide.three {
  left: 400px;
  top: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-animation: fadeThree 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeThree 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeThree 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_image .slide.four {
  left: -100px;
  top: 500px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-animation: fadeFour 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeFour 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeFour 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_info .slide_info.one {
  left: 400px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-animation: fadeThree 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeThree 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeThree 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_info .slide_info.two {
  left: 800px;
  top: 400px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-animation: fadeFour 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeFour 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeFour 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_info .slide_info.three {
  left: 400px;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOne 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeOne 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeOne 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_info .slide_info.four {
  left: 0;
  top: 400px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-animation: fadeTwo 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeTwo 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeTwo 16s infinite;
}
/* Slider Styles */

#slider_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slider {
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
#slider #slides_image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1300px;
  height: 1300px;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 16s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotate 16s ease infinite;
  animation: rotate 16s ease infinite;
}
#slider #slides_info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -400px;
  width: 1100px;
  height: 1100px;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 16s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotate 16s ease infinite;
  animation: rotate 16s ease infinite;
  z-index: 5;
}
#slider #slides_info .slide_info {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}
#slider #slides_image .slide {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/defaulticon/icons/png/256x256/media-pause.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
/* Text Styles */

#slider #slides_info .slide_info h2 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#slider #slides_info .slide_info p {
  color: #666;
  font: 13px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #eee;
}
/* Button */

#slider a.button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0 15px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font: 13px/40px Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #353637;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 40px;
  outline: none;
}
#btn-produtos {
  border: 2px solid #353637;
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#btn-produtos:hover {
  background-color: #353637;
  color: #fff;
}
#slider a.button:hover {
  background-color: #353637;
  color: #fff;
}
#slider:hover #slides_image,
#slider:hover #slides_info,
#slider:hover #slides_image .slide,
#slider:hover #slides_info .slide_info {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
#slider:hover .slide img {
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}
.equipamentos h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
.equipamentos > p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 45%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  #slider_wrapper {
    height: 700px
  }
  #slides_image {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #slides_info {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
/* Animation Keyframes */

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  20% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  45% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  75% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  95% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "rotate" {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes "rotate" {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  45% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  95% {
    transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeOne {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  22% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "fadeOne" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  22% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes "fadeOne" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  22% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeTwo {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  47% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  55% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "fadeTwo" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  47% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  55% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes "fadeTwo" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  47% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  55% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeThree {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  72% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "fadeThree" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  72% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes "fadeThree" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  72% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeFour {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  95% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  97% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "fadeFour" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  95% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  97% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes "fadeFour" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  95% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  97% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider_wrapper">
  <div id="slider">

    <div id="slides_info">
      <div class="slide_info one">
        <h2>Title Three</h2>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a
          sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <p>
          Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <a class="button" href="#">Visualizar</a>
        <a class="button" href="#showcase">Solicite um orçamento</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide_info two">
        <h2>Title Four</h2>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a
          sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <p>
          Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <a class="button" href="#">Visualizar</a>
        <a class="button" href="#showcase">Solicite um orçamento</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide_info three">
        <h2>Title One</h2>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a
          sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <p>
          Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <a class="button" href="#">Visualizar</a>
        <a class="button" href="#showcase">Solicite um orçamento</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide_info four">
        <h2>Title Two</h2>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a
          sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <p>
          Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <a class="button" href="#">Visualizar</a>
        <a class="button" href="#showcase">Solicite um orçamento</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="slides_image">
      <div class="slide one">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/4/41tAxTu.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide two">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1hjGftu.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide three">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/4/4OIJyak.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide four">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/68BYSto.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quero que fique algo assim eu não estou sabendo deixar a imagem posicionada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Não é preciso usar o `float` nesse caso. Eu gosto de usar o `display:inline-block` que é compatível com várias propriedades CSS.

Fiz apenas um exemplo abaixo. Use a propriedade `display` com valor `inline-block`.

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px){
    #imagem{
        display:inline-block;
        margin: auto;
    }
    #texto{
        display:inline-block;
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: então @Diego Souza eu coloquei aqui e mesmo assim ele nao se meche ai pensei que fosse meu id="slider_wrapper" que tava barrando por conta do tamanho porem nao foi eu aumentei ele um pouco mais mais mesmo assim ele nao se meche

Comment: Sabe o JSFiddle ? http://www.jsfiddle.net ? Faça um com o seu código e poste aqui. Assim ficará mais fácil para entendermos a questão.

Comment: nao conheço amigo posso fazer assim editar o post com a minha alteração que fiz ai fica melhor vou editar la pera ai

Comment: editei la amigo da uma olhada na media querie que fiz no css

Comment: Vixi. É plugin de slider. Primeiro, desativa essas animações. Tem como ? Deixa passando o slider apenas. Se não ele fica nessa giração, não tem como. Porquê está com `position absolute` os elementos. E não pode se você fazer isso. Outra alternativa talvez é você desativar o slider nessa resolução e fazer no HTML normal. Outra alternativa é usar o Owl Carousel. Eu gosto bastante por causa de seus recursos responsivos. http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

Comment: existe uma maneira de eu fazer isso sem tirar o css tipo o efeit pode ser ate outro mais tem que ser feito com html e css e que e de uma cliente o site entende e como ela ta pagando ela que assim tem algoma dica do que pode ser feito tipo colocar em uma outra posição sem ser essa algo assim

Comment: sua segunda opcao "Outra alternativa talvez é você desativar o slider nessa resolução e fazer no HTML normal" como pode ser feito isso nao entendi muito bem mais parece ser a que eu preciso no caso como nao dar para fazer do jeito que esta